# TypeScript incorrectly inferring function parameter when mapping over config object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sorry for the poor title, but I'm not sure how to describe the issue I'm seeing. My use case is fairly complicated, but I'll do my best to distill it down to the bare essentials.

I have a list of config objects which have an `eventName` whose value corresponds to the name of an event which can be triggered in my application. When said events are triggered, any listeners are called with an `event` object of the appropriate type.

E.g.:

```js
type EventHandler<E> = (event: E) => void;
// Just a map of eventname -> handler (with appropriate event type as an arg)
type EventMap = {
  onStart: EventHandler<StartEvent>;
  onEnd: EventHandler<EndEvent>;
};
const configs = [
  buildConfig('onStart'),
  buildConfig('onEnd')
];
```

I then want to map over this config object and construct another list of (different) config object who have a `handlerFactory` property which is a function that builds the appropriate event handler for the event. The reason this is a function is to provide a closure which can supply additional context to the event handler.

```js
type AdditionalContext = unknown; // Actual type is not important for this example
type HandlerConfig<E extends keyof EventMap = keyof EventMap> = {
  eventName: E;
  handlerFactory: (context: AdditionalContext) => EventMap[E];
};
```

The issue is that in my `.map` callback TS is unable to infer the proper event type:

```js
const handlerConfigs: HandlerConfig[] = configs.map(({ eventName }) => {
  return {
    eventName,
    handlerFactory: (context) => {
      // FIXME: Why is e `any`? It should be the event type that corresponds to the eventName event handler.
      return (e) => {
        console.log('Did something cool!', context);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGAnYBRAbhAdsKBeKA3gFBSlTwBcUmArgLYBGEiA3EQL5GiRQqYAm6LDnzEyUBlQDOwRAEtMAczadu0IdgAS8AQBtmAHhQA+PFAAUEDNiooAlHlNoA9nP5su4dQA9Z8AMao1sAAKl4GIab4IVAQvlj8UrzB2nqGCgBmzLymAPy8UFSYVsweAPRlUABSNDLkUHTwYFDOGbHBmPB00AC0pgAWOvz6iBYA7nLA-eRgYIjOc3LwwNAl2FBq5Ek65IiKdp48GsAAsk1mYmTOmHBIwLYpQyMGt8jHxmzi13z8D8Kpw0MP3eKg8m2OAGFrhk5IojLF4gIkgBrCAgVrJYRnZr4VHotrHbFRQgkMhrYAAOS6EFsKiIRH81zqMjuf2wUMwMLhAHJrq9gNziQR2sIqd0qLybghkNyoOw2IzMHUEmzgByuQZJT9BRcRdgxTSoFqBLL5QymThFVykvgANos5AAGliAgAumCvFAAIL8fiTOTXeC6DkrXxmGiYZGYZxjTAsKAVb2BGhBjaeuRJaM4OR0MDOZA6HAZfMbfoZhFdMD6Q7QAEjdWw+FxFZIqB4jGE864tEd4JEi6k0jkg20wdQQZpRAAMQCwHzICo5kVofu3t9-sDweuK4cuFMnbAtpQ7o4HkVdQngMQDcUUiodeYN9trrMVthUgAdI0wOZzMLh9Scq7qYlykIgEDADQiCYCS4jiAB3SOmO4iXiMM6BPOi7Ls2wGwXB+GJlOACSAAaJwoFQADq-QgFA5bQAABjoIAMfkRE4FI-TODQuj8BI0BTKswRpjwUzLFAjKIOBUh5q2c6lkJoqAeS45PMwH7IfhUDgZB0EWBAuGgVp+Hns4+gfroziKOY3IACJuFAUjON0UwKIoEnOGZACE3LOthvh2J8xlkGaxmcOIZrsIFQA) showing the error.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: added the type definition for `EventHandler` to the code above.

Comment: This is ultimately the issue reported in [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); inside your `map` callback everything is a union and TS can't follow correlated unions that way. The supported approach is a fairly substantial refactoring of types as described in [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to make things generic in a compiler-appropriate indexed way, as shown in [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WPJyeN). You might prefer to just use a type assertion instead. Does this fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

Comment: Yes, this is extremely helpful! The issues you linked definitely describe the issue I'm seeing (though it will take some time to fully wrap my head around the issue and fix). If you add an answer, I will accept it.
As an aside, you clearly have a deep understanding of this, any recommendations on how I can improve my understanding? I feel like I'm at an intermediate level, but there seems to be a huge lack of documentation/resources out there that are geared towards learning TS at an advanced level. Everything I find seems to be for beginners mostly.

Comment: I'm probably the wrong person to ask, since I learned mostly by reading the handbook, release notes, and GitHub issues.  But that's a lot of material, much of which is noise (especially GitHub issues) so I don't know that I'd recommend it unless you have that kind of time/effort to spend.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with

```
const handlerConfigs: HandlerConfig[] = configs.map(({ eventName }) => {
    return {
        eventName,
        handlerFactory: (context) => {
            return (e) => { // error, implicit any
                console.log('Did something cool!', context);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

is that inside the callback function, the type of `eventName` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types). If you could [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `eventName` to each member of the union and check it separately, you'd have a chance to get desired behavior:

```
configs.map(({ eventName }) => {
    if (eventName === "onEnd") {
        return {
            eventName,
            handlerFactory: (context) => {
                return (e) => {
                    console.log('Did something cool!', context);
                };
            }
        } satisfies HandlerConfig<"onEnd">;
    } else return {
        eventName,
        handlerFactory: (context) => {
            return (e) => {
                console.log('Did something cool!', context);
            };
        }
    } satisfies HandlerConfig<"onStart">;
});
```

But that's redundant. You'd think the compiler could just check a single code block against each possible narrowing, keeping track of the correlation between union members across different lines of code, but that's not how it works.  (See https://twitter.com/SeaRyanC/status/1544414378383925250 )

This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The easiest thing you can do is just give up on the compiler checking accurately and widen things or [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) things until it stops complaining. For example:

```
configs.map(({ eventName }) => {
    const ret: HandlerConfig = {
        eventName,
        handlerFactory: (context) => {
            return (e: StartEvent | EndEvent) => {
                console.log('Did something cool!', context);
            };
        }
    };
    return ret;
});
```

That works because `(x: StartEvent | EndEvent) => void` satisfies both event handlers.

---

On the other hand, if you need the compiler to follow logic like this, you can take the approach recommended in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), where you use generics instead of unions.

The idea is to write operations in terms of some "basic" key-value mapping type, and [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) either that basic type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.

The goal is that you want things that would normally look like unions to look like a single generic type.  Here's how I'd do it for this example code. The basic type looks like:

```
interface EventMap {
    onStart: StartEvent,
    onEnd: EndEvent
}
```

(note that I called *this* `EventMap`, and renamed *your* `EventMap` to `HandlerMap`, since it's more descriptive):

```
type HandlerMap<K extends keyof EventMap = keyof EventMap> =
    { [P in K]: (event: EventMap[P]) => void }
```

The type `HandlerMap` is the same as before (as your `EventMap`), but now it's generic, so `HandlerMap<K>` is just the piece of the object with the key `K`.

And we have to change `HandlerConfig` too:

```
type HandlerConfig<K extends keyof EventMap = keyof EventMap> = {
    eventName: K;
    handlerFactory: (context: AdditionalContext) => HandlerMap<K>[K];
};
```

That `HandlerMap<K>[K]` is similar to `(event: EventMap[K]) => void` except that it *distributes over unions in `K`*.  That is, it's a *distributive object type* as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.  This assumes that if `K` is a union, then `handlerFactory` should also be a union. If you *don't* care about that, you can just write

```
type HandlerConfig<K extends keyof EventMap = keyof EventMap> = {
    eventName: K;
    handlerFactory: (context: AdditionalContext) => (event: EventMap[K]) => void;
};
```

but that ends up just blurring the distinction between the two union members, and you couldn't write a version that actually changed based on which event type you got.

Anyway, from here we can finally write `handlerConfigs` by making the `map()` callback generic, saying that it coverts an `EventConfig<K>` into a `HandlerConfig<K>`:

```
const handlerConfigs: HandlerConfig[] = configs.map(
    <K extends keyof EventMap>({ eventName }: EventConfig<K>): HandlerConfig<K> => {
        return {
            eventName,
            handlerFactory: (context) => {
                return (e) => {
                    console.log('Did something cool!', context);
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

Now when you inspect `e`, you'll see it's `EventMap[K]`, the type you expect it to be (and you could, if you want, delegate it to something that depends on `eventName`).

---

Is it worth that refactoring? Not obviously from this use case. It's so easy to just annotate `e` with something wide and move on.  But in some situations, this refactoring is the only way to come close to type safety.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGAnYBRAbhAdsKBeKA3gFBSlTwBcUmArgLYBGEiA3EQL5GiRQqYAm6LDnzEyUBlQDOwRAEtMAczaciC4MwBm8AMbQh2ALLwwhEmQD2mOEmBUbyA8AA050lb78qnpxy7hoAAl4AQAbZmMwAB4AaSgIAA8NASkoAGsIEAtNXgwjEzx0zOzc4UiAPjw3QigAbQAFKAUoGIBdKgAKCDy7UvywBtaASjxKtAs5fihVfx4nAGErTTlFWPikrH5UjKycp0jCnZL9k0rRau7hADl4OggqGJUiIh0rGSgZW28excxl1YA5FYHMAAWcapdsDc7lQgdYEMgAdM2K9MO9Nt9hL9-lE4Z4wYUCPEetD7lA8QIkewUW8cKj-ql8LVPshnPEBK02LNoABBfj8OTAORWeChX4aJKFGiYNKYCwAd0wbG4QRC-HCiGxKzWiWSWyKuz6wAO+COex6FUJFxJtzJj2qAAs1RqAGK6YAWRAgTqoiW9PkCoUisVWP0jXCVYJhCImWLlWptFRc+krKQAOjoJg6HSJkOApOm4cqYjIqPeiAgvSj6uYWsUVvE4jzpNcjbITujiDdOg9Xp9od1RbMbbbFeANEQmCgXSHJZHI7LFnCadCFkUHQBABFJh8LHdgA6FPXXkuAIQAtm+wdsefianVO-VdgfeBCqTLCCpasaus3shjicpzHFQhmTJZUwzLMc2Ja5bULUZhzIOQci6G07jwXB8AAIg8AQsJGOdGwAydENvGCoVtVsyKgDsay7d1PW9acrySWcH2o4ipxnBDCOoxtF2XVd1y3HcpD3StDyUKAT1Cc9LwHVi-z40h7z4zh52fKRXzkd85E-KBv1rcDVhwzBPCw8olOmeJQikaBONIxtm0o9jSFo10GL7ZiFOANi+Ic7iI0cviBIgFc1w3bcpjE-dJOPCwzwvaSfNA1zG1Ukd1LITTtN0-TDM1YyolMkELJArkXmM9NMzAbNczQ6B2D80taSgMcqAKusGxHZy7iott3OYbteyYjoWN8ni0vEAKyRBJwoAAH14AQnGa5TkrRJcwqEyLRPEg8j2SxL5Owa8puyqzHzvKyHOAjhUsqtEcEGwq-lTDrnSMt7FFqVpChTRRqqzaodQ2FIDWOC1Tmg3rGsxbA6zjIYPs7RGYjOYs0oc3ieoa-rbxe4bGP7U7WMm9bSBmtaKdIULwuEqLd1iw6ZLkjaw0u6iMrIrK225wsWCAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent and thorough answer! I feel like I understand what is happening much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Your handlerFactory type definition is returning a type. But the way you are using it is, it returns a function, with the event object as its first parameter.

So just resembling that fixes the issue for me.

```
type HandlerConfig<E extends keyof EventMap = keyof EventMap> = {
    eventName: E;
    handlerFactory: (context: AdditionalContext) => (e: EventMap[E]) => void;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! That does get rid of the inferred `any`, but the type isn't quite right. `EventMap[E]` is the event handler function (sorry, I should have included that in the question's code snippets...I will update it). So in your solution `handlerFactory` returns a function whose argument is an event handler. I want the argument type to be the event type.

Comment: Your suggestion did nudge me towards a solution: `handlerFactory: (context: AdditionalContext) => EventHandler<ExtractEventType<EventMap[E]>>`. It's not ideal, but it seems to work. I wish I understood why this works but just `EventMap[E]` does not...